# Google API : Plus.People.Search: Unable to find class 'Plus'.

Tags: java, android

Can any one please help which jar file i need to include for Plus.People.Search?

I added all jar files available in **google-api-services-drive-v2-rev97-java-1.16.0-rc/lib** directory.
Authentication and all other things are working which are related to Drive API.

Right now my requirement is I want to get User object by passing emailid. I found this link, but couldn't able to execute the code, because its unable to identify Plus.People.Search class.

Can any body please help me ASAP.